# How to display Switch behind the thumb android studio

Tags: android, xml, api, android-layout, android-studio

Here is my current code it appear the text in thumb, but what I want is to display text behind in the the box like demo

[image]

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track_selector"
        android:showText="true"
        android:textOff="Hide"
        android:textOn="Show"
        android:switchMinWidth="75dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector" />
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to use either https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0

[image]

**OR**

you can do something like
Text is not shown by default under Material theme since the switch widget assets don't work well with text.

You can change this using the [`android:showText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#attr_android:showText) property or [`Switch.setShowText(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setShowText(boolean)) method.

**xml**

```
 <Switch
        ...
        android:showText="true" />
```

**programatically**

```
mSwitch.setShowText(true);
```

please check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setShowText%28boolean%29

Comment: When I use showText="true" it appear in thum button not be hind and what I want is behind the button